# remove weird characters from LCD display

Tags: python, bash, lcd

I'm trying to display the pH value from a sensor, for this I have a `bash` script in which I retrieve the pH value and generate a file with the last pH recorded:

```
READ=`dd if=/dev/ttyUSB1 count=5 status=none` #Reads pH from USB
echo -n "$READ" > $PWD/.2displaypH.tmp  #Creates file with last pH
```

Then I use `.2displaypH.tmp` in a script in `python`, so I can send it to the 4x20 lcd display:

```
while True:

        peache = open("/home/pi/Documents/SensorTempRpi/Scripts/.2displaypH.tmp").read()

        lcd.lcd_display_string("Hello", 1)
        lcd.lcd_display_string("pH: %s" %peache, 2)
        lcd.lcd_display_string("Bomba: OFF", 3)
        lcd.lcd_display_string("Enfriador: ON", 4)

time.sleep(2)
```

The problem is that the pH in the 4x20 screen shows a weird character at the end. 
If I send any value manually, such as `echo -n "7.123" > .2displaypH.tmp` I don't get any weird characters, which makes me think is a problem of a `newline`, unfortunately, my code (`echo -n "$READ" > $PWD/.2displaypH.tmp`) doesn't prevent it. Any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps you can use `.encode()` in python to generate a binary string and log this. If there are special (hidden) characters, you can detect these. A wild guess is that somehow [control characters](http://ascii.cl/control-characters.htm) are passed as well (like NUL, SOH, etc.)

Comment: If you mean to read 5 bytes, then you should set the blocksize in your `dd` to `1` else you are trying to read 5 blocks of 512 bytes each.... `dd bs=1 count=5 if=...`

Comment: Or you could keep just the first 5 bytes of whatever you read with an extra line between `READ=...` and `echo...` which has `READ=${READ:1:5}`

Comment: Or delete everything that is not a digit or a period from `READ` with `READ=$(tr -cd '0-9.' <<< "$READ")`

Comment: Thank you, Mark! Your first answer worked perfectly!